# How do I import node modules into TypeScript with Intellisense?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I'm trying to import the node module, Q into my TypeScript project and would like to get Intellisense working 100%

This works, but q is set to `any`, which means no intellisense. I also have to use a mix of Q and q, which can get confusing.

```js
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/q/Q.d.ts" />

module example {

    // no intellisense on q
    var q = require('q');

    // we do get intellisense on deferred though
    var deferred: Q.Deferred<void> = q.defer();
}
```

We can't do this because Q is a module, so the `:Q` part results in an error.

```js
/// <reference path="Scripts/typings/q/Q.d.ts" />

module example {

    // BAD: this doesn't work
    var q: Q = require('q');
}
```

File structure:

```
Q is in /node_modules/q/
Q.d.ts is in /Scripts/typings/q/Q.d.ts
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 SP4 and TypeScript 1.4

note: I've seen similar questions on stack, but those solutions don't work for the newer versions of typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q: typeof Q = require('q');
```

Or, you can move the `require` call outside the `module` block and use `import instead:

```
import q = require('q');
```

Comment: ``var q: typeof Q = require('q');`` seems to partially work. I have access to the methods, but not the interfaces (for example I can't use q.IPromise<void>, I must use the capital Q so I still have a mix of lower and upper Q's.


When I add ``import q = require('q');`` outside of the module, Visual Studio can no longer find external ``ts`` files with the same module name. example would be ``module example { var service: myService; }`` with error: ``Cannot find name 'myService'.``